# Selenium testing PayPal sandbox

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, paypal-sandbox

I have a test suite using Selenium Firefox driver that produces a shopping basket and then sends the information to PayPal for payment. 
The process was working up until this week, when I was upgraded to the version of the PayPal API that allows Guest Checkout. 
The problem I have is the page doesn't seem to finish loading and is doing ajax calls for stats etc. So when I issue a Selenium command to my PayPal Sandbox page it's timing-out waiting on the page to finish. 
Is there any way for me to override and get the DOM even though its still polling for stuff? I can see the information I need in my browser, just can't access it.

Comment: Possibly, but should really try to diagnose the slow pages/timeouts before fiddling. Can you recreate manually, outside Selenium?

Comment: If I hit the page directly in the browser, then it loads almost immediately. But if I hit the same page via Selenium WebDriver it's still making "stats" calls so the page doesn't finish.